# Should small i to capital I in review approved?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Many times in review I have seen people do editing of i to I. Or some 2-3 case changes.

e.g. See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1125282 -> is Rejected.

Should this edits approved?
Aren't these too minor?

I also think these edits are minor. What should be checking in review such time?

Comment: There's more that could be fixed in that post: Superfluous indentation of code, grammar, title, tags and formatting. So yes, that edit is too minor in comparison to what could have been done.

Comment: My rule of thumb for editing is that there has to be a least two (and preferably three) major-ish things wrong - poor formatting AND noise, or needs a code block AND spelling/grammar errors. If i -> I is the only thing wrong, leave it.

Comment: If it's all that's wrong with a post, yes, it should be approved, but in this case, there were other problems too.

Comment: Anyone else who constantly wants to fix the lowercase "i" in the title?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends.

If there are more things to improve in the post, they should be improved for example in the suggestion you linked to, the code indentation can be fixed and the quoted error should be formatted properly as well. In such cases I tend to either reject as too minor, or Improve this myself if I have time.

If those minor things are the only things that need improvement then I tend to approve.

One more thing to consider is the age of the post: if the post is old (for me over 6 months) then such edits are always too minor and don't justify bumping the whole question to the front page.

Comment: Dangit; beat me to it. Just what I would have said!

Comment: @Andrew yep, pretty sure I posted this myself in the past, too lazy to go and find it. :P

Comment: Means if original post have indented & formatted code and only those things need improvement then should approved? Aren't they minor?

Comment: Interesting consideration of the age of the post. Wouldn't you also take the views into account? We of course want to show off quality posts.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk They are *minor*, yes; but the question is, are they *too* minor? I believe Shadow describes the difference here very well.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk only one change is always too minor in my opinion. But for example five "i" turned to "I" might be just enough, considering everything I said in the answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Agreed until. If we improve something on such posts then should we uncheck "Suggested edit was helpful"? –

Comment: @SomnathMuluk good question. If it was only "i" changed to "I" and there were other things to improve then yes, I will uncheck it to have the suggested edit rejected. If he changed more but still missed some things I'll probably leave the box checked to approve the suggestion. Can't define a general rule for this, each case is specific.

Comment: I often go around capitalizing words or adding some punctuation fixes. There is a reason it is 6 char min, and not like 30 char min for an edit. I personally find a question that is not capitalized (as in lower case I and what not). If people choose to reject what would make a question more readable that is their choice I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Those type of edits are acceptable if they are complete. If what edit was the only thing to correct in the post, then they are fine; if there is something else that needs to be edited, then they are not fine.

This doesn't mean that correcting the spelling of a word, the space before punctuation, or the used punctuation, is not an acceptable suggested edit. They are acceptable, as long as they are complete.

Comment: If we improve on such posts then should we uncheck "Suggested edit was helpful"?

Comment: It's what I would do, if the suggested edit was incomplete, and I edit the rest of the post.